# How to navigate to another layout if the android app is inactive for 5 minutes

Tags: android

I am working on an android application. If the application is inactive or not using for 5 minutes, it should navigate to another activity. I have no idea about this. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following code in your activity..

### **CODE**

```
public static final long DISCONNECT_TIMEOUT = 300000; 
// 5 min = 5 * 60 * 1000 ms=300000

private Handler disconnectHandler = new Handler(){
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    }
};

private Runnable disconnectCallback = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Perform any required operation on disconnect         

        Intent i=new Intent(this,newActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
    }
};

public void resetDisconnectTimer(){
    disconnectHandler.removeCallbacks(disconnectCallback);
    disconnectHandler.postDelayed(disconnectCallback, DISCONNECT_TIMEOUT);
}

public void stopDisconnectTimer(){
    disconnectHandler.removeCallbacks(disconnectCallback);
}

@Override
public void onUserInteraction(){
    resetDisconnectTimer();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    resetDisconnectTimer();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    stopDisconnectTimer();
}
```